# How to mirror an instance in Abaqus/CAE?

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to mirror an instance in the assembly module of Abaqus/CAE.
There is an option in Abaqus/CAE part module within part copy that let us mirror any part. Still. I am trying to do the same within assembly module of Abaqus/CAE. 
Does anyone knows a way to do the same thing within assembly module of Abaqus/CAE?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to copy/mirror a part in the Assembly module of the CAE. Here are a couple of workarounds:

**Workaround 1** Create a copy/mirror in the Part module before instancing it in the Assembly. Then in the Assembly module, create an instance of each.

**Workaround 2** Create a couple of instances of your Part in the Assembly module. Use the *translate*, *rotate*, and *constraint* tools to reposition one of the Part instances.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the model database tree a part should be copied.
2. Then in the pop-up window check to mirror it according to a plane.
3. Finally, on the Assmebly module the mirrored part should be placed as an instance in the assembly.